Supermicro X10DAC 5 Beeps And No Video
I tried booting my Supermicro X10DAC board. It came with 2 CPU's already installed. The power LED is on and the SAS LED is blinking (both green). The first tone from the speaker is a melody. After a few seconds it then beeps 5 times. The manual says it is an input or output error. No video output to the monitor.
https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=18188
https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C612/MNL-1563.pdf
CPU:
Intel Xeon E5-2620 v4
RAM:
Samsung M393A2G40DB0-CPB2Q Cisco UCS-MR-1X162RU-A
Proof this memory is supported:
https://store.supermicro.com/16gb-ddr4-2133-mem-dr416l-sl01-er21.html
RAM Installed:
P1 DIMMA1, P1 DIMMB1, P2 DIMME1, P2 DIMMF1
I tried posting with a single stick in P1 DIMMA1. I had 8 sticks and every one of them resulted in the 5 beep error codes, except for 1 stick (no speaker sound at all), which I discarded for now. So I am only using 4 sticks for testing until I can get further.
I tried using 3 other video cards. All of them have DVI outputs. The fans all spun up. None output video.
I tried 2 keyboards. They light up so I assume they are not causing the issue.
Removing all memory from the board results in the appropriate 5 beeps followed by the long beep.
I tried another power supply. Phanteks AMP 750. The only thing I haven't tried is removing the heatsinks and CPU's.
I followed this post:
https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/weird-supermicro-x9-drw-if-issue-5-beeps-no-output-devices.24900/post-405371
I removed the battery and shorted the jumper.
My last attempt will be removing the CPU's unless anyone has any insight that can help me figure this issue out.
I left it on to see what would happen and eventually a never ending beep sounded. The heatsinks were too hot to touch, so I am guessing the CPUs were overheating. So perhaps that is the issue as to why it is not posting and the thermal paste needs reapplied.
Update:
I disassembled the CPUs and tried each one, one at a time in the CPU 1 slot. Nothing changed, still getting the 5 beeps and no video. The board should have BIOS for these CPUs since they were installed and said to be working. The only thing I have left to try is an older CPU which I don't currently have. I have contacted Supermicro and the tech support from where the board came from, I won't hear back until Monday so I've no choice but to shelve it for now. I think it must be a bad board.

I had to use an R9 290X video card and was able to get video output from that. From there I could get into the BIOS and had to put the OPROM PCIe into Legacy mode. Before it was disabled. Now any video cards tried before will work.
